# Nested shapes in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, shapes, android-shape

I am trying to draw a shape that has three rectangular shapes:

1. solid color
2. gradient
3. white line

How do I do that?

When I try this, it does not work. The layout has the parent color.

```
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:height="60px"
    >
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle" 
        android:height="30px"
        >
        <solid 
            android:color="#ff297baf" 
            />
    </shape>
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:height="30px"
        >
         <gradient
  android:type="linear"
  android:startColor="#ff297baf"
  android:endColor="#ff16c0e3"
  android:angle="270"/> 
    </shape>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:height="3px"
        >
        <solid 
            android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
            />
    </shape>
</shape>
```

I am trying to make a gradient in 3 colors. Start with a solid color `#ff297baf`, at 60% start a gradient from `#ff297baf` to `#ff16c0e3` and add a while line at the end.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information here. Do you have example code of what you're trying so far? Why do you need a solid color AND a gradient? Is it a transparent gradient overlay? The white line, is it an outline? Should it go inside the shape?

Comment: Please add your comment to the question and format it a bit.

Comment: its not transparent overlay. White line is an outline. Normally I would do this in HTML: "border-bottom: solid 2px white". It does not have to do inside but I can't get any other shapes on the view. The compiler complains that <shape> is supposed to be root.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to look into using multiple shapes, you should try a LayerListDrawable. Something like this works for me, but only for your example height of 60px. You may have to modify it to suit your needs exactly, but this should get you a good start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#ff16c0e3"
            android:startColor="#ff297baf"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="57px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        <size android:height="3px" />
    </shape>
</item>
```