# Draw text inside oval within another oval on canvas android

Tags: android

I have new requirement to draw oval within oval  using android canvas.now done oval within oval but did not draw text inside oval.sample image added given below for reference.[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a circle inside a circle using Android xml shapes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613308/how-to-draw-a-circle-inside-a-circle-using-android-xml-shapes)

Answer (score 2):

for resolution (480 x 800)

in onCreate()

```
setContentView(new SampleView(this));
```

create class

```
private static class SampleView extends View {

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        //1
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        RectF oval1 = new RectF(0, 0, 250,250);

        Paint p1 = new Paint();
        p1.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        canvas.drawText("Parent", 30, 50, p1);
        canvas.drawOval(oval1, paint);


        //2
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        RectF oval2 = new RectF(50, 50, 150, 150);

        Paint p2 = new Paint();
        p2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        canvas.drawText("Child", 75, 75, p2);
        canvas.drawOval(oval2, paint);
    }

}
```