# How to implement android view pager with relaying background images for each page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, animation, android-viewpager

Please look through the following view pager:
[View Pager with relaying background images](https://i.imgur.com/pIy1qIq.gifv)

How can I implement this. I've tried to extend ViewPager and override onDraw() but I fail to achieve the behavior observed in the gif.

I've implemented the view with transparent circle which is being scrolled over the background. My main problem is the drawing part of the background images: smooth transition, cases when half of the circle of the other page is also visible when page is slightly being scrolled left or right, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The example project is [here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/ViewPagerClipped/tree/master) on GitHub.

You can implement what you are looking for by using the `ClipDrawable` class. Each image is placed into an `ImageView` within the `CoordinatorLayout` stacked one upon the other. By using the `ViewPager` callback methods, you can control how much of each `ClipDrawable` is shown based on the offset reported by the `ViewPager`.

Here are some screen shots of moving through three pages in a sample project. I did not implement the moving circle, but I think you have that figured out.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Demo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEXKY.gif).

Comment: Thanks! It's a very elegant solution. Only the third image isn't being displayed, I'm figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

here is tip for your problem.

Take a frame layout and place a Image view and then view Pager on it.
Now prepare a Layout which is having a transparent circle at its center.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can change the Image in the main layout on by using the View Pager's addOnPageChangeListener and on scrolling you can get the desired effect.

```
Use the ViewPager.onPageChangeListener:

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int      positionOffsetPixels) {}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // Change your Image here.
}
});
```

Comment: Make note that he would also have to use a Layer-List shape drawable for the ImageView to achieve the desired Circle in the center, I would reference the OP to this source. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613308/how-to-draw-a-circle-inside-a-circle-using-android-xml-shapes]

Comment: I've implemented the transparent circle part, but I fail to implement the smooth transition of background images:

onPageSelected won't work because it's a discrete operation you must actually go to the page do get the callback called. What if you scroll a little bit left and you have the half of the circle of the second page visible on your screen as well?

Comment: You can implement the image change part in the onPageScrolled funtion.

Comment: so you're suggesting to somehow detect if other circle from another page is visible and draw corresponding bitmap?

Comment: I must handle the right splitting of each image in onDraw() for being able to display the right portions of each image for each circle. I just don't know how to handle it

Comment: You can use android DiscreteScrollView library and sync it with view pager to get the desired output. Use DiscreteScrollView in place of ImageView.

https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView