# How to draw a circular stroke inside a circle?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I'm trying to achieve this effect, but I can't make the white circular stroke inside the circle. In my implementation, the white stroke appears outside the circle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <corners android:radius="10dip" />

            <stroke
                android:width="5dip"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <solid android:color="#f50000" />
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Expected output:-

[image]

Comment: i can`t post the image as i have very low reputation!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613308/how-to-draw-a-circle-inside-a-circle-using-android-xml-shapes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I accomplished this using a `<layer-list>` and an `<inset>` oval shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#f50000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <inset
            android:insetTop="5dp"
            android:insetLeft="5dp"
            android:insetRight="5dp"
            android:insetBottom="5dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <stroke
                    android:color="#fff"
                    android:width="5dp"/>
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can control the inset amount and the stroke width by changing the values in the second item

Answer (score 0):

here you go. Just modify a little your file to have two items and add a padding on the second.
I hope it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#f50000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: In this xml you have an oval, not a circle.

Comment: @GiuseppeLabanca it's a flexible background, if you put it in a square container it will be a circle. If you want yo force it to be always square you can use the `size` stub but that is not always a good idea, dependeing on what use you plan for the layer-list...

Answer (score 0):

You need an xml like this (optimized):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#007" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#f00" />
        <size
            android:width="25dp"
            android:height="25dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

or xml like this (not optimized):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#007" />
        <size
            android:width="25dp"
            android:height="25dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="8dp"
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <solid android:color="#f00" />
        <size
            android:width="45dp"
            android:height="45dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <solid android:color="#007" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

for this result:

[image]

Comment: Try to optimize your drawables: you actually need **only 2** circles: one is filled and one is used for the "stroke".

Comment: check my answer to achieve this in two drawables only. also instead of using size, you can add padding to the item.

Comment: It depends if the external and internal circles has the same colors.

Comment: @GiuseppeLabanca if they have different color, you just need to add a second solid element also in the second item

Comment: In the given example, they don't. It's a filled color and a ring over it.

Comment: I edited my post with @gbaccetta 's hint forced to 25dp size